# wordpress subscriber with contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7, user-registration

Does anyone know if with contact form 7 it is possible to have a checkbox that when it is activated by the visitor, this visitor is registered as a wordpress user, as a subscriber?

After the comment of Howard E, the question changes to...

How can be used `wpcf7_before_send_mail` for register a new user with the data of the form?

something like this, but I don't know if it is completely correct...

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'register_user' );

function register_user($cf7) {
    $form_id = $cf7->id();
    
    if ($form_id == 300 || $form_id == 301 || $form_id == 302) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance();
    }
    if ($submission) {
        if (empty($posted_data)) { return; }
        
        $accept = $posted_data['acceptance-register-yes']; //acceptance check to be registered
        if (empty($accept)) { return; }
        
        $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
        $name1 = $posted_data['your-name'];
        $name2 = $posted_data['your-last-name'];
        $name = ''; //here will go function to delete spaces and generate user name from $name1 + $name2
        $pass = ''; //here will go function to random password
        
        function create_user($n,$p,$e){
            if (!username_exists($n)  && !email_exists($e)) {
                $user_id = wp_create_user($n, $p, $e);
                $user = new WP_User($user_id);
                $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
            }
        }
        create_user($name,$pass,$email);        
    }   
}
```

many thanks

Comment: Of course this is possible.  You can use hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` - however, your question as it stands is off topic, and you should consider revising it.

Comment: There's at least one plug-in for the purpose. https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-registration-contact-form-7/

Comment: I think frontend-registration plugin doesn't allow a check box to register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user and hook into `wpcf7_before_send_mail` like this.

```
function wp_create_custom_account(){
  
  // Get the WPCF7 Submission instance
  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        // Get the posted variables
        $username = isset($posted_data['username'])?$posted_data['username']:'';
        $password = isset($posted_data['password'])?$posted_data['password']:'';
        $eml = isset($posted_data['eml'])?$posted_data['eml']:'';
        
        // This can be radio or checkbox. Adjust your code accordingly
        $radio = isset($posted_data['radio'][0])?$posted_data['radio'][0]:'';

        if ($radio) {
          $user = $username;
          $pass = $password;
          $email = eml;
          if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
            $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
          } 
        }
    } 
  
  
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','wp_create_custom_account');
```